# How to change date format in text file linux/unix

Tags: regex, linux, date, unix, sed

**The following is text file myfile.txt**

```
7022122465,0,0,day,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022597642,0,0,day,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022848906,0,0,day,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022191546,0,0,day,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022180761,0,0,day,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022125589,0,0,day,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022224472,0,0,day,2015-09-29 10:48:33
```

I want to change last column date  format from 2015-09-29 to 2015:09:29 using regular expression please help me.

I have tried like this but replacing regular expression (i am beginner to linux)

```
sed -r  's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/g' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Read about [*capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [*replacement backreferences*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

Comment: @narasimharao - Please confirm if you will get data always in this format. What if you get `-` anywhere else? Are you sure that it will never happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/\1:\2:\3/g' myfile.txt
```

`()` are capturing groups. Whatever results are matched using capturing groups are stored and can be backreferenced during substitution using `\1`, `\2` etc.

```
([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})
<--------> <--------> <-------->
1st group  2nd group  3rd group
```

Comment: I like your solution best because it allows me to change the order in the date.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than grouping, You should try :

```
sed 's/-/:/g' myfile.txt
```

if you want to edit file in place use `i` option like : `sed -i 's/-/:/g' myfile.txt`

Comment: Better option if you just want to replace `-` with `:`, which OP wants in the first place.

Comment: obviously that's what OP asked for

Comment: there's no reason to escape `-` and `:`, just use `'s/-/:/g'`