# how to change date-format in a log file using bash, avoiding while loop

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, date-format

This is not a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43697746/959179) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37523058/959179), but the details make it differ.

My input log file looks like:

```
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:20:24 EEST 2020 -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:20:50 EEST 2020 -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:13 EEST 2020 -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:44 EEST 2020 -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:45 EEST 2020 -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:52 EEST 2020 -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:53 EEST 2020 -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:54 EEST 2020 -=- 49.6
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:56 EEST 2020 -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- Sat Aug 15 02:21:57 EEST 2020 -=- 49.1
```

and the output should look like:

```
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:20:24 EEST -=- 48.6
...
```

So it is simple enough to change the format of a date in bash using

```
date -d ${date_in_current_format} "+DATE_IN_NEW_FORMAT"
```

It is also possible (albeit inefficient) to iterate over the log file using a while loop and change the dates line by line (see the 1st link again).

However, I am looking for a bash solution that uses `sed` or `perl` (or `awk` or anything else for  that matter) to carry out the same task.

The tip of what I have tried but still does not work are the following search and replace functions:

```
perl -pe "s/(.*) -=- (.*) -=- (.*)/\1 -=- $( date \2 "+%Z %Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S" ) -=- \3/" <file>
```

and with `sed` something similar:

```
sed "s:\(.*\) -=- \(.*\) -=- \(.*\):\1 -=- $( date -d \2 "+%Z %Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S" ) -=- \3:" <file>
```

In both cases the problem is that I cannot get the search and replace substitution "\2" to be expanded within the bash `date` command execution.

Comment: This might help: [Formatting date strings in a file with linux bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61015078/3776858)

Comment: @anubhava: [Eastern European Summer Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Summer_Time)

Comment: @Cyrus: Reason why I asked because I kept trying `TZ=EEST` in my `date` command and it wasn't working. After your answer I figured in terms of a Unix command it is `TZ=EET` instead.

Comment: In Perl, `$(` will be interpreted as a variable. And `\1` is better written as `$1`.

Comment: @TLP but is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @nass if you care for efficiency and have large log files to convert, calling `date` for every line would make any script extremely slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk` using only string functions, you can avoid calling the `GNU awk` datetime functions or the external command `date`, as we want to modify only the month and re-order the data.

```
> cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=FS="-=-" }
{
    split($2, arr, " ")
    m=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", arr[2])+2)/3
    $2=sprintf(" %04d-%02d-%02d_%s %s ", arr[6], m, arr[3], arr[4], arr[5])
    print
}
```

Usage:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:20:24 EEST -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:20:50 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:13 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:44 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:45 EEST -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:52 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:53 EEST -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:54 EEST -=- 49.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:56 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:57 EEST -=- 49.1
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=" -=- "
}
{
   cmd = sprintf("TZ=EET date -d \"%s\" +\"%Y-%m-%%d_%T %Z\"", $2);
   if ((cmd | getline output) > 0)
      $2 = output
   close(cmd)
} 1' file
```

```
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:20:24 EEST -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:20:50 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:13 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:44 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:45 EEST -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:52 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:53 EEST -=- 48.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:54 EEST -=- 49.6
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:56 EEST -=- 49.1
TEMP MON -=- 2020-08-15_02:21:57 EEST -=- 49.1
```

Comment: The OP is clearly on Linux, so this is more for future visitors; this is the least portable of these answers, as it requires GNU `date`.

Comment: `date -d` command is mentioned in OP's question itself.

Comment: Yes yes, I just feel that it needed to be pointed out for people who are not necessarily on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Using core module `Time::Piece` in Perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/-=-\s+\K(.*)(?=\s+-=-)/convert($1)/e;
  sub convert {
    $s = $_[0];
    $s =~ s/\s+EEST\s+/ /;
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($s, "%a %b %d %T %Y");
    $res = $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S");
    "$res EEST"
 }' file
```